# python web server hangs on ssl.wrap_socket(socket, keyfile="path/to/file.pem", certfile="path/to/file.pem", server_side=True)

Tags: sockets, python-3.x, ssl, https, webserver

I am trying to write a web server in python 3.x that supports https requests. The following is my web server code.
The code hangs at 
**httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(httpd.socket, keyfile="path/key.pem", certfile="path/cert.pem", server_side=True)** 
This line is in main at the bottom of this program. I would like to know why the code hangs here.

```
import time, http.server, cgi, ssl    
HOST_NAME = 'localhost'
PORT_NUMBER = 9999

class MyHandler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_HEAD(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type","text/html")
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        "responding to GET request"
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes("some html text", 'utf-8'))
        self.wfile.flush()

    def do_POST(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        self.end_headers()
        ctype, pdict = cgi.parse_header(self.headers['content-type'])
        ctype, pdict = cgi.parse_header(self.headers['content-type'])
        if ctype == 'multipart/form-data':
            postvars = cgi.parse_multipart(self.rfile, pdict)
        elif ctype == 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded':
            length = int(self.headers['content-length'])
            postvars = cgi.parse_qs(self.rfile.read(length), keep_blank_values=1)
        self.wfile.write("some content here")
        self.wfile.flush()

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    server_class = http.server.HTTPServer
    httpd = server_class((HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER), MyHandler)

    **#code hangs on this line**
    httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(httpd.socket, keyfile="path/key.pem", 
                    certfile="path/cert.pem", server_side=True)
    print(time.asctime(), "Server Starts - %s:%s" % (HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER))
    try:
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    httpd.server_close()
    print(time.asctime(), "Server Stops - %s:%s" % (HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER))
```

When I try to debug, I see that the hang is at **self._context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile)** in SSL.py. Last line in the below code.

```
class SSLSocket(socket):
    """This class implements a subtype of socket.socket that wraps
    the underlying OS socket in an SSL context when necessary, and
    provides read and write methods over that channel."""

    def __init__(self, sock=None, keyfile=None, certfile=None,
                 server_side=False, cert_reqs=CERT_NONE,
                 ssl_version=PROTOCOL_SSLv23, ca_certs=None,
                 do_handshake_on_connect=True,
                 family=AF_INET, type=SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, fileno=None,
                 suppress_ragged_eofs=True, npn_protocols=None, ciphers=None,
                 server_hostname=None,
                 _context=None):

        if _context:
            self._context = _context
        else:
            if server_side and not certfile:
                raise ValueError("certfile must be specified for server-side "
                                 "operations")
            if keyfile and not certfile:
                raise ValueError("certfile must be specified")
            if certfile and not keyfile:
                keyfile = certfile
            self._context = SSLContext(ssl_version)
            self._context.verify_mode = cert_reqs
            if ca_certs:
                self._context.load_verify_locations(ca_certs)
            if certfile:
                self._context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile)
```

I gave the path correctly to certfile and keyfile as well. What am I doing wrong? Why is that the code hangs here

PS: please feel free to edit my question for any betterment.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to wrap the listener socket. But you must wrap the connection to the client, i.e. the result you got from accept. Don't know what the right hook is in the httpd server architecture for this.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich :  thank you for your response, but I am afraid that didn't work for me. As I am new to ssl wrapping of sockets, I copied the code **ssl.wrap_socket(...)** from a different website, but I could not reach out to them on how to get it working. Also in another website, it mentioned that there was some bug in python ssl wrapper. I need to find more about it.